# Kind of a proof for the circumference of a circle?

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification, circles

Hello fellow StackExchange members!

Some time ago, I was thinking about the proofs concerning the circumference of a circle and had the following idea. Having insufficient knowledge in trigonometry and calculus at that time, I couldn't get myself to "do the math". But after taking classes, I now have the ability (and time due to quarantine!) to share my proof with you. I do not know if this counts as a proof since we have a predefined definition of $π$, but here is my way of thinking:

In a regular polygon of $n$ sides and with a distance $r$  between its vertices and its center, we can use trigonometry to find the length of one side. ($n∈\mathbb{Z}^+$ and $r∈\mathbb{R}^+$)

First of all, we have to find the central angle $α$ between any two neighboring "radii" forming an isosceles triangle when looked at with the side connecting the two vertices. To find this, we can divide the central angle of $2π$ to the number of sides:

$α=\frac{2π}{n}$

Next, we can use the law of cosines to calculate the length of the third side of the isosceles triangle, which also happens to be the side length of the regular polygon. Let's call the side length $s$.

$s=\sqrt{r^2+r^2-2⋅r⋅r⋅\cos(α)}=\sqrt{2r^2-2⋅r^2⋅\cos(\frac{2π}{n})}\\=r\sqrt{2-2\cos(\frac{2π}{n})}$

To find the total perimeter ($P$) of the regular polygon, we have to multiply the number of sides by the side lenght:

$P=n⋅r\sqrt{2-2\cos(\frac{2π}{n})}$

Now, when $n$ approaches infinity, our polygon should approach to being a circle; so if we take the limit  of this expression with $n$ approaching infinity, we should be able to approximate the circumference of the circle with a radius of $r$. (I urge you to plot this function into a graphic calculator with $x$ instead of $n$ as a variable. As $x$ fets larger, the function approaches the value of $2πr$. I was really happy to see this for the first time.)

Before the limit, let's simplify our expression. I was careful with the domains and ranges of the trigonometric functions and rewriting the expression in the following way should not cause any problems while taking the limit at infinity.

$n⋅r\sqrt{2-2\cos(\frac{2π}{n})}=n⋅r\sqrt{2(1-\cos(2⋅\frac{π}{n}))}\\=n⋅r\sqrt{2[1-(1-2\sin^2(\frac{π}{n}))]}=n⋅r\sqrt{4\sin^2(\frac{π}{n})}=2⋅n⋅r⋅\sin(\frac{π}{n})$

(That simplification was quite magical for my simple mind!)

Let's now take the limit:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} n⋅r\sqrt{2-2\cos(\frac{2π}{n})}=\lim_{n \to \infty}2⋅n⋅r⋅\sin(\frac{π}{n})=2r⋅\lim_{n \to \infty}n⋅\sin(\frac{π}{n})$

Now this was where I got stumped for a while; until I learned L'Hospital's Rule of course! We can rewrite the expression as follows:

$2r⋅\lim_{n \to \infty}n⋅\sin(\frac{π}{n})=2r⋅\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sin(\frac{π}{n})}{\frac{1}{n}}$

We now see that the limit gives us $\frac{0}{0}$ as $n$ approaches infinity so let's use L'Hospital's Rule:

$2r⋅\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sin(\frac{π}{n})}{\frac{1}{n}}=2r⋅\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\frac{d}{dn}(\sin(\frac{π}{n}))}{\frac{d}{dn}(\frac{1}{n})}\\=2r⋅\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\cos(\frac{π}{n})⋅(-\frac{π}{n^2})}{-\frac{1}{n^2}}=2r⋅\lim_{n \to \infty}π⋅\cos(\frac{π}{n})\\=2πr⋅\lim_{n \to \infty}\cos(\frac{π}{n})$

Since the limit of the fraction $\frac{π}{n}$ approaches $0$, the value of $\cos(\frac{π}{n})$ approaches $1$:

$2πr⋅\lim_{n \to \infty}\cos(\frac{π}{n})=2πr⋅1=2πr$

And this is how I ended up with the circumference of a circle. Thank you very much for sticking around until the end!

Is this a mathematically correct way of proving the circumference of a circle?

Comment: it’s important to state what is involved in the limit process: in this case, the number of sides is increasing without bound. A restatement of the limit is that if I choose any small positive number  $\epsilon$, there is always a number N  such that  n>N  implies that  |2πr−$p_r$(N)|<$\epsilon$ .

Comment: By the way, the cancelling out of the "1 over n squared" terms is due to n being a positive integer.

Comment: @Pj30 I see, that is the epsilon definition of limits, right?

Comment: "proving the circumference of a circle" ? You mean that the ratio between circumference and diameter is $\pi$ , which either is by definition (in this case , nothing has to be proven) , or you define $\frac{\pi}{2}$ to be the first positive root of $f(x)=\cos(x)$ , with which then you can try to show that the ratio is in fact $\pi$.

Comment: I'd regard the use of the Hospital as a bit "circular" here. To differentiate the sine function you need to know that the limit $\lim_{x\to0}(\sin x)/x$ equals $1$, and essentially that's the limit you are calculating.

Comment: @IlyasSeckin yes.

Comment: I've read your proof and confirmed that this proof is mathematically correct. Also, it's nice that this proof has some amount of rigor even if the over-all outline is intuitive. But I can also see that this question is also asked here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/973271/prove-that-circumference-of-circle-with-radius-r-is-2r-pi, you can take a look. :)

Comment: @Peter I guess what I did was to verify the ratio then?

Comment: @AnginaSeng but wouldn't the limit I was trying to calculate be limx→0(sin(pi*x))/x?

Comment: I would say a problem with your proof is that the definition of trigonometric functions uses the fact that a circle of radius $1$ has perimeter $2\pi$, so I think this proof is an instance of cyclic reasonning. Apart from that I did not check all the details but I think it is a nice computation and I did not spot any mistake

Comment: @IlyasSeckin Yes, the circumference itself is not $\pi$ (unless we choose the diameter as the measure unit)

Comment: Well, $\lim_{x\to 0}(\sin\pi x)/x=\pi\lim_{x\to 0}(\sin\pi x)]/(\pi x)=\pi\lim_{y\to0}(\sin y)/y$ so I'd contend these limits are essentially the same...

Comment: Historically, Archimedes determined the value of the ratio circumference:diameter (within quite good bounds) and this was defined as "$\pi$". Later, the concept of the unit circle was invented, nevertheless often $\pi$ is defined via the cosine. Archimedes' method can numerically calculate $\pi$ without trigonometric tools. I think, strictly speaking, we should start this way , although ( perhaps of didactical reasons) usually we start with the trigonometric functions.

Comment: @Peter I guess Archimedes' method for computing the $\pi$ also proves that the ratio between a circle's circumference and diameter is constant, right? But are there other classical arguments for this fact? Do you know if Euclid proved it in the Elements? I feel like the Greeks just assumed this as fact before Archimedes.